# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, system-installation, kernel

I'm a newbie software developer. Which version would you recommend for home-use? What I wish to use with the computer is learn tools such as Android Studio or Php. However the hardware changes and improvements bug me a little as they may be worth a while. Can you help me out?

The Ubuntu 20.04 LTS uses kernel 5.4 as opposed to the 5.11 which Ubuntu 21.04 Uses.

Also the machine I use is Dell Inspiron-15-3567. Which is not very powerful and the updates may be very useful.

Comment: Seems like you have already answered your own question. If still in doubt, try both and judge for yourself.

Comment: You can run Ubuntu 16.04 and still install the latest kernel AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 20.04.2 LTS.

```
$ hostnamectl
```

reveals that my Kernel is Linux 5.8.0-53-generic

`$ sudo apt update` and `$ sudo apt upgrade` will do I guess.